# Image Background for Start Screen in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to change the background image of the start screen from an app?
Example: I have an generated image within the app and want to set it as background image (for tiles) of my start screen in windows phone 8.1 by a simple tap on a button.

Comment: You mean lockscreen image ??

Comment: Do you want to change the start screen image shared across tiles? Do you want to change the background of ONE tile (your selfcoded app)? Do you want to change the background of the lockscreen?

Comment: Of course I mean this new feature of WP 8.1 where you can set one image as background for all tiles on the start screen. For all tile with transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no API that allows changing the Windows Phone 8.1 Start Screen background image programmatically.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the man's question. The background behind transparent tiles cannot be set programmatically with 3rd party APIs, but the individual tiles can be set just fine with either the TileUpdater for 8.1, or ShellTile for 8.0.

Comment: I think he gave the correct answer to the question, but the question itself is very misleading...