# Can I set the "start background" from a Windows Phone 8.1 (Store or Silverlight) app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Although it is possible to set the lock screen in a [Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (but [not in a Windows Phone 8.1 app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), I can't seem to find any information on setting the "start background".

Is it possible to set the "start background" image via an API?

Note that this is set manually via Settings > start + theme and is different from the lock screen image.

Comment: The only question I could find on MSDN wasn't answered by an MS employee. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/eff51469-0427-44db-9f59-a1753b0795f9/whats-the-image-resolution-used-for-start-background?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Background for Start Screen in WP 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081357/image-background-for-start-screen-in-wp-8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to set 'Start background' image from third part app. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081357/image-background-for-start-screen-in-wp-8-1) question answer comments by [Claus Jørgensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95309/claus-jorgensen-msft)